# nginx sub-folder with separated root

Tags: nginx, alias

I have a little problem. I have a wordpress installation in

```
/var/www/xyz/wordpress
```

and now I want to have a piwik installation in the path

```
/var/www/xyz/piwik
```

My current nginx configuration looks like this:

```
server {

    ...

    root /var/www/xyz/wordpress;
    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
    }

    location /piwik/ {
            root /var/www/xyz/piwik;
    }

    location ~ ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
            try_files $1 =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. Any ideas / tips to configure nginx?

Comment: You have wrong `root`. It should be `root /var/www/xyz/;`. `piwik` will be added automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have understand it. `/` should point to `/var/www/xyz/wordpress` and `/piwik` to `/var/www/xyz/piwik`. If I change the root to `/var/www/xyz`, `/` points no longer to `/var/www/xyz/wordpress`.

Comment: I mean root in piwik location

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I get a 404 error. And there is no entry in the error.log about it.

Comment: What url do you access?

Comment: It was my fault, it's working now. But now on, I had to specify the fastcgi php "handler" again. Is there a better solution instead of having the php part twice?

Answer (score 3):

This is a common misunderstanding in nginx configuration.

Try this:

```
location /piwik/ {
    alias /var/www/xyz/piwik/;
}
```

Comment: Nop, this does not work. But now with `root` as directive, it works.

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles upon this answer, the problem with this answer is that when using the `alias` directive, you also need to have the trailing slash in the aliased location, if your location regex contains the trailing slash.